# Use static object in LibreOffce python script?

Tags: python, libreoffice

I've got a LibreOffice python script that uses serial IO. On my systems, opening a serial port is a very slow process (around 1 second), so I'd like to keep the serial port open, and just send stuff as required.

But LibreOffice python apparently reloads the python framework every time a call is made. Unlike most python implementations, where the process is persistent, and un-enclosed code in a module is run once, when the module is imported.

Is there a way in LibreOffice python to persist objects between calls?

```
SerialObject=None

def return_global():
  return str(SerialObject)  #always returns "None"

def init_serial_object():
  SerialObject=True
```

Comment: My answer should help solve the problem, but here are things that could be added to your question to pinpoint the issue (and perhaps help others with this question): Where are your scripts located (location=document, user, or application, and where is the imported file?), how are they run (for example, connect to LO listening on a socket, or from within LO as a macro, or as a service defined by an LO extension), and what is the example code that imports and calls this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a simple bug. Add `global` and then it works.

However, it may be that the real problem is your setup. Here is a working example. Put the code in a file called `inctest.py` under `$LIBREOFFICE_USER_DIR/Scripts/python/pythonpath/incmod/`.

```
def init_serial_object():
    global SerialObject
    SerialObject=True

def moduleVersion():
    return "2.0"  #change to verify that this is the most recently updated code
```

The code to call it should be located in the user profile directory (that is, `location=user`).

```
from incmod import inctest
inctest.init_serial_object()
msgbox("{}: {}".format(
    inctest.moduleVersion(), inctest.return_global()))
```

Run the script by going to *Tools > Macros > Run Macro* and find it under *My Macros*.

Be aware that `inctest.py` will not always get reloaded. There are two ways to reload it: restart LibreOffice, or force python to reload it by doing             `del sys.modules[mod]`.

The `moduleVersion()` function is not necessary but helps you see when the module is getting reloaded — make changes to that line and then see whether the output changes.

Comment: I'm using a Document module, but the solution works there as well. Removing the module level declaration, and using local global declaration. It needs to be guarded to check that the variable exists, not just that the variable has ben set.